# How to modify one column from flat file source A with mapping defined in flat file source B

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have flat file source A with 2 columns

```
Col1 Col2
ada  1
das  2
2312 1
```

and second flat file source B with mapping for Col1 (converting color id to color name)

```
Col1 Col2
1    Red
2    Green
3    Blue
```

I have both file loaded into Flat File Source. Im wondering how to replace Ids in Source A  with color names from source B? Expected solution is:

```
Col1 Col2
ada  Red
das  Green
2312 REd
```

Any quick solution?

Comment: `select tblA.col1,tblB.col2 from tblA join tblB on tblA.col2 = tblB.col1`

Comment: Any SSIS component need for this? Im not SSIS expert:). Could you extend this a bit? .. Dont explain me this SQL code:)...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Flat file source` set it to be loaded to a proper table in your database as destination. Say you created two tables `tbl1` and `tbl2`:

You can now join these two tables, in the next step (`DFT` or `EXEX SQL Task` or where-ever) and you can see desired columns as output:

```
SELECT tbl1.col1 AS [Name], 
       tbl2.col2 AS [Color]
FROM   tbl1 
       JOIN tbl2
         ON tbl1.col2 = tbl2.col1
```

If you don't want to do it in two steps you can use a `Merge Task` and join the two like above. Refer to the image below (in your case both sources will be flat file source, but use a left join with tbl1 on the left as we don't want to loose that data if color code is not available):

[image]

Comment: Generally I have 2 flat file sources :) but it helps me to build me detailed workflow:). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'Merge Join' option in your SSIS package and you can choose Left/Right join as per your requirement.